# How to list results for several calculations in R

Tags: r

I have loaded two source files, performed some iterative calculations, and then i need to display/export the results. There are hundreds of iterative calculations, hence hundreds of results. However, only results of the final calculation is displayed.

In this example, i have shortened the list of calculations to only 3. Please refer to line 7 (k in 1:3). How do i get R to display result of all calculations?

Many thanks in advance to those who can offer help. If this question has already been asked before, a link would be great. I could not find this probably because i do not know the right terms to search for.

```
# Load files
d1<-read.csv('testhourly.csv',sep=",",header=F)
names(d1)<-c("elapsedtime","units")
d2<-read.csv('testevent.csv',sep=",",header=F)
names(d2)<-c("eventno","starttime","endtime","starttemp","endtemp")

# Perform for calculations 1 to 3
for(k in 1:3){
a<-d2[k,2]
b<-d2[k,3]
x<-d1[a:b,]$q
a2<-d2[k,2]-1
b2<-d2[k,3]-1
y<-d1[a2:b2,]$q

z <- (x-y)}
results <- sum(z)

# Export results
write.csv(results, file = "results.csv")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: I guess you are ending up with a single value per iteration, then you should store the result in a vector. You should create a vector called results and put it inside the loop, and fill it with your final result for each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saving your output inside the loop for every iteration, so your loop only returns the final value of the last iteration.

```
temp=vector("list",3)

for(k in 1:3) {
        a<-d2[k,2]
        b<-d2[k,3]
        x<-d1[a:b,]$q
        a2<-d2[k,2]-1
        b2<-d2[k,3]-1
        y<-d1[a2:b2,]$q

        temp[[k]] <- (x-y)
    }

results <- sum(unlist(temp))
```

Comment: Does not work though. I got an error message:
"Error in temp[k] <- (x - y) : replacement has length zero".

By the way, what does "temp=rep(NA,3)" do? 
And, is there any difference between using square brackets and normal brackets in "temp[k] <- (x-y)"? 
Sorry for fundamental questions. I am new in this.

Comment: I guess the result in z is a not a number, didn't see that. `rep(NA,3)` creates a vector of length 3 filled with NA's. Square brackets are for indices, normal brackets are for operators and functions.